# R dataframe, changing the value in a variable with a value from the same variable

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame which looks like this

```
ID  Name  Surname  Country    Unique_number
1   John   Snow      UK          12345
1   John   Anderson  USA         53214
1   John   David     UK          NA
2   Kim    Snow      UK          62321     
2   Kim   Anderson   USA         77832
2   Kim    David     UK          NA
```

I want a data from which will look like this (Notice the change in unique_number )

```
 ID  Name  Surname  Country    Unique_number
1   John   Snow      UK          12345
1   John   Anderson  USA         53214
1   John   David     UK          12345
2   Kim    Snow      UK          62321     
2   Kim   Anderson   USA         77832
2   Kim    David     UK          62321
```

Can someone help with to do this in R studios ?

Thank you

Comment: do you want to replace the missing value with the last seen?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `df$Unique_number[2]`, is it an empty string? You can first convert it to `NA`

```
 df$Unique_number[df$Unique_number == ''] <- NA
```

and then use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package

```
df$Unique_number <- zoo::na.locf(df$Unique_number)
```

This will carry over the last non-NA observation to replace NAs.

---

Edit

To preseve original `NA` values, split your dataframe in two and operate only on the part that contains the values you want to replace (I am assuming empty strings)

```
df0 = df[is.na(df$Unique_number), ]
df1 = df[-is.na(df$Unique_number), ]
```

(alternatively use `split(df, is.na(df$Unique_number)`) and then call the code above on `df1` and finally `rbind` them.

---

Edit 2

Here is another approach, I'm pretty sure it will be slower than the one above that uses `zoo` but lets you specify your own string

```
MISSING_STRING = '' # String you want replaced with last non-NA value
x0 <- c("1", "2", "", "3", "4", "", "", "5", "6", NA, "", "7", "8", 
"", "9", "10", "") # Example vector
x <- x0 # Store initial example vector for comparison at the end
missing.ids <- which(is.na(x) | x == MISSING_STRING)
replacement.ids <- missing.ids - 1
replacement.ids[1 + which(diff(replacement.ids) == 1)] <- replacement.ids[diff(replacement.ids) == 1]
na.ids <- is.na(x)
x[missing.ids] <- x[replacement.ids]
x[na.ids] <- NA
# Compare initial vs final value
cbind(x0, x)
    x0   x   
[1,] "1"  "1" 
[2,] "2"  "2" 
[3,] ""   "2" 
[4,] "3"  "3" 
[5,] "4"  "4" 
[6,] ""   "4" 
[7,] ""   "4" 
[8,] "5"  "5" 
[9,] "6"  "6" 
[10,] NA   NA  
[11,] ""   "6" 
[12,] "7"  "7" 
[13,] "8"  "8" 
[14,] ""   "8" 
[15,] "9"  "9" 
[16,] "10" "10"
[17,] ""   "10"
```

Comment: Thank you, But there is a problem . I cannot replace all the NA's with the previous values because i have other NA's which i want to keep as NA's.

Comment: My Ideal code would be if it could only replace SURNAME Anderson with the previous non NA value.

Comment: Have a look at my edits, I'd personally use `zoo` or write an `Rcpp` function, but it's possible you can have a vectorized implementation that is faster than my second edit (I'm sure it can be optimized but don't have the time to think about it right now)

Answer (score 0):

With `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name, Country) %>%
  fill(Unique_number)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Name, Country [4]
     ID Name  Surname  Country Unique_number
  <int> <fct> <fct>    <fct>           <int>
1     1 John  Snow     UK              12345
2     1 John  David    UK              12345
3     1 John  Anderson USA             53214
4     2 Kim   Snow     UK              62321
5     2 Kim   David    UK              62321
6     2 Kim   Anderson USA             77832
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Name = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Kim"), class = "factor"), 
    Surname = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Anderson", 
    "David", "Snow"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    Unique_number = c(12345L, 53214L, NA, 62321L, 77832L, NA)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name", "Surname", "Country", "Unique_number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, But there is a problem . I cannot replace all the NA's with the previous values because i have other NA's which i want to keep as NA's.

Comment: My Ideal code would be if it could only replace SURNAME Anderson with the previous non NA value.

Comment: @Kp_Data I don't quite understand your desired output. You should include that example in your question.

Comment: I Have Edited the question.

Comment: @Kp_Data I've updated my answer. Looks like you just need to add a `group_by`. The rows are automatically sorted by group